# How to write zsh completer for an option which needs to be completed differently depending on its prefix?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I'd like to write completion for a program taking `--dsn=<database-specification>` option where database specification is of the form `backend://something-else` and where "backend" can take one of several predefined values, such as `postgresql`, `odbc` or `sqlite3` and I want to complete the rest of the option differently depending on which value is chosen.

I know how to complete the backend using something like

```
_arguments '--dsn[database connection string]:DSN:(sqlite3\:// postgresql\://)' ...
```

but I don't know how to provide the backend-specific completions later. I thought that I should use `$state`, but I don't see how to set it to the different values depending on the backend chosen.

Could someone please explain how to do it or, maybe, point me to a different way of doing what I want?